# How can I transform a list of binary digits into integers?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to transform a list of binary digits into integers. With the `Table` function, I produce four lists of binary digits of length 32. Then I tried to turn these lists into integers, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
Table[b[i] = 1, {i, 0, 32}];
Table[b[k] = b[i + j] = Mod[(b[i + j - 5] + b[i + j - 32]), 2], {i, 32, 35}, {j, 0, 31}]
FromDigits[{b[k]}, 2]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using more or less your approach, I use `RandomChoice` to create some "binary numbers". Next you can use `FromDigits` and map it on this list.

```
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {4, 32}]
```

Edit: I assumed these "binary" numbers to be random. If you want to use it for the numbers you created, just map it on those. My `RandomChoice` produces numbers of the same format.

Comment: great - you are welcome. And make sure you understand `Map` (or just `/@`) well, that's very useful

Comment: Just for fun. `FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ 
  randomChoice == (Fold[ 2 #1 + #2 &, 0, #] & /@ randomChoice)`

Comment: @TomD - nice one, it took a bit for me to understand the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
BaseForm[number, base]
```

and  just run every number through the command.

```
Example:
BaseForm[2^^1101101,2]
```

Comment: What if I have 10000 numbers?

Comment: @user5484 You would then use `Map` or it's shortform `/@`.