# Splitting a binary number into smaller parts and converting each smaller part back to decimal

Tags: string-manipulation, number-bases

This is my first Mathematica post and I would be obliged if you could be patient with me.

I have the following large binary number $1111010010001001100011010101111110000101101110110011100101$ which I have split into 4 smaller parts.

$1111\ 01001000100110001101010\ 111111\ 0000101101110110011100101$

How would I convert each of the 4 smaller parts back into decimal values i.e 1111 is the same as 15 etc.

I used `IntegerString` to convert the number to binary and `StringTake` to break the binary number down into the smaller groups and now I am stuck.

Comment: related? [How can I transform a list of binary digits into integers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18151/106)

Comment: S.Cook, could you clarify if the input is a `String` ("1111 01001000100110001101010 111111 0000101101110110011100101") or a list of  `Integer`s (1111, 01001000100110001101010, 111111, 0000101101110110011100101})?

Comment: It was a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "1111 01001000100110001101010 111111 0000101101110110011100101";

FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ StringSplit[string]
```

> {15, 2378858, 63, 1502437}

**Update:** To work directly with with original string:

```
sPartition = FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ StringJoin /@ TakeList[Characters @ #, #2]&;

string0 = "1111010010001001100011010101111110000101101110110011100101"; 
sPartition[string0, {4, 23, 6, All}]
```

> {15, 2378858, 63, 1502437}

**Update 2:** The answer above assumes the input is a `String`. If, instead, it is a list of `Integer`s, then, in addition to the methods in other answers you can also do

```
#. (2)^(# - Range @ # & @ Length @ #) & /@ 
 IntegerDigits[{1111, 01001000100110001101010, 111111, 0000101101110110011100101}]
```

> {15, 2378858, 63, 1502437}

Comment: your last update does not work as expected.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci, make sure you have space between `Dot (.)` and `2` so that you are not multiplying  `#` with `.2`.

Comment: Interesting. When I pasted the space is disparaged

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {1111, 01001000100110001101010, 111111, 0000101101110110011100101};
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ IntegerDigits@d
```

> {15, 2378858, 63, 1502437}

Answer (score 1):

```
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ (ToString /@ d)
```

where `d = {1111, 01001000100110001101010, 111111, 0000101101110110011100101}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Fold[2 #1 + #2 &, 0, #] & /@ (IntegerDigits@d)
```

> {15, 2378858, 63, 1502437}

where

```
d = {1111, 01001000100110001101010, 111111, 0000101101110110011100101};
```